# TensorFlow Batch Processing of sparse BOW Inputs has poor CPU Utilization

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to build a text classification network that uses a bag of words representation for the inputs. The first layer is a lookup and summation of dense word embeddings. I want to train using mini batches.

Following https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/342#issuecomment-160354041 I use `nn.embedding_lookup_sparse()` to load Bag of Words from a  minibatch into a tensor.

The rest is pretty much a standard neural network with `nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits()` loss function and stochastic gradient descent optimization.

When I run my code on a machine with more 40 cpu cores, I only achieve a cpu utilization of ~200%, thus 38 cores are doing no useful work. I find this odd, given that gradient computation in mini batches can be massively parallelized and the gradient descent optimization should be non-blocking Hogwild style...

Here is some more code

```
vocabularySize = 146532
embeddingSize = 300
batchsize = 640

trainInputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
trainLabels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64,shape=(batchsize))
sp_indices = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)

sp_shape = tf.constant([batchsize, vocabularySize],tf.int64)
embeddings = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocabularySize, embeddingSize], -1.0, 1.0))
sparseBOW = tf.SparseTensor(sp_indices, trainInputs, sp_shape)
h1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.embedding_lookup_sparse(embeddings,sparseBOW,None))

inner = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([embeddingSize, 32],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(float(embeddingSize))))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32]))
h2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h1,inner) + biases)

softmax_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([32, 2],stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(32)))
softmax_biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2]))
logits = tf.matmul(h2,softmax_weights) + softmax_biases

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, trainLabels))

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.001).minimize(loss)

#...ommiting the data loading part. I load everything into python datastructures first, so there is no file io involved.
_, loss_val = sess.run([optimizer, loss], feed_dict=feedDict)
```

Is there a way to profile where exactly computation time is spent and to identify bottle necks? Is this even the right way to handle sparse input data? Should I just go dense?